# Problema con Route en Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

Hola quiero crear un route, segui paso a paso un tutorial y no consigo hacer que funcione

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// Routes
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routes';

// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './components/heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  entryComponents:[
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }



// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/shared/navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './components/about/about.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './components/heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.route.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home', component: 'HomeComponent'},
    {path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },

];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports : [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Me arroja este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El componente no debe ir entre comillas